# How to change 4-space indentation when using "kotlin-vim` plugin

Tags: indentation

I just installed `kotlin-vim` plugin.
The plugin looks like using 8-spaces indentation.

How can I change it 4-spaces indentation?

(To indent all codes I used `gg=G`. Maybe I'm using wrong way for indent all the text.)

Comment: What are your tab settings in your .vimrc?

Comment: I see, it's just depends on default tab setting. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After the plugin calls in your `.vimrc` have a selection of the following (depending on desired configuration):

```
set tabstop=4     // how tabs are displayed
set shiftwidth=4  // how far a shift moves a line
set softtabstop=4 // how many spaces are inserted by pressing tab*
set expandtab     // insert tabs as spaces
```

* if you are inserting tabs after text it will insert up to `softtabstop` spaces until the number of characters on the line is a multiple of `softtabstop`